# Using Unity/Vuforia in a SherlockFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm working on an app that uses Vuforia for AR/interactive content through a Unity extension. I'm having trouble figuring out how to integrate Vuforia into the app (along with Unity for rendering).

I am targeting Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) and up.

Currently my app is set up so that there is a SherlockFragmentActivity which starts several background tasks and uses a ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter to switch between several fragments. One of these fragments is the Vuforia fragment.

So far, what I've tried is instantiating a UnityPlayer and returning the View in the fragment's onCreateView:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    UnityPlayer mPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this); // Put your activity object here
    int glesMode = mPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
    boolean trueColor8888 = false;
    mPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);
        View view = mPlayer.getView();
        return view;
}
```

However, Vuforia fails to load when I do this. Unity does load, but I get a black screen and no output from the camera.
Logcat:

```
07-02 14:59:25.695: D/Unity(18351): Creating OpenGL ES 2.0 context (RGBA32 8888 24/8)
07-02 14:59:25.900: D/Unity(18351): GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_texture_npot     GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_depth24 GL_ARM_rgba8 GL_ARM_mali_shader_binary GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer 
07-02 14:59:26.520: D/dalvikvm(18351): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.androchill.socialsquare.fingerprintdemo/lib/libQCARWrapper.so 0x41efb450
07-02 14:59:26.520: E/Unity(18351): Unable to find QCARWrapper
07-02 14:59:26.525: D/dalvikvm(18351): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.androchill.socialsquare.fingerprintdemo/lib/libQCARWrapper.so 0x41efb450
07-02 14:59:26.525: E/Unity(18351): Unable to find QCARWrapper
07-02 14:59:26.750: I/Unity(18351): DllNotFoundException: QCARWrapper
07-02 14:59:26.750: I/Unity(18351):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) QCARNativeWrapper:trackerManagerInitTracker (int)
07-02 14:59:26.750: I/Unity(18351):   at QCARNativeWrapper.TrackerManagerInitTracker (Int32 trackerType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.750: I/Unity(18351):   at TrackerManagerImpl.InitTracker (Type trackerType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.750: I/Unity(18351):   at DataSetLoadBehaviour.Awake () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.750: I/Unity(18351):  
07-02 14:59:26.750: I/Unity(18351): (Filename:  Line: -1)
07-02 14:59:26.815: I/Unity(18351): Trackable USC_campus_map lost
07-02 14:59:26.815: I/Unity(18351):  
07-02 14:59:26.815: I/Unity(18351): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)
07-02 14:59:26.815: D/dalvikvm(18351): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.androchill.socialsquare.fingerprintdemo/lib/libQCARWrapper.so 0x41efb450
07-02 14:59:26.815: E/Unity(18351): Unable to find QCARWrapper
07-02 14:59:26.815: D/dalvikvm(18351): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.androchill.socialsquare.fingerprintdemo/lib/libQCARWrapper.so 0x41efb450
07-02 14:59:26.815: E/Unity(18351): Unable to find QCARWrapper
07-02 14:59:26.820: I/Unity(18351): DllNotFoundException: QCARWrapper
07-02 14:59:26.820: I/Unity(18351):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) QCARNativeWrapper:getInitErrorCode ()
07-02 14:59:26.820: I/Unity(18351):   at QCARNativeWrapper.GetInitErrorCode () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.820: I/Unity(18351):   at QCARUnityImpl.CheckInitializationError () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.820: I/Unity(18351):   at QCARUnity.CheckInitializationError () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.820: I/Unity(18351):   at DefaultInitializationErrorHandler.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.820: I/Unity(18351):  
07-02 14:59:26.820: I/Unity(18351): (Filename:  Line: -1)
07-02 14:59:26.820: I/Unity(18351): QCARWrapper.Start
07-02 14:59:26.820: I/Unity(18351):  
07-02 14:59:26.820: I/Unity(18351): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)
07-02 14:59:26.825: I/Unity(18351): DllNotFoundException: QCARWrapper
07-02 14:59:26.825: I/Unity(18351):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) QCARNativeWrapper:getInitErrorCode ()
07-02 14:59:26.825: I/Unity(18351):   at QCARNativeWrapper.GetInitErrorCode () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.825: I/Unity(18351):   at QCARUnityImpl.CheckInitializationError () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.825: I/Unity(18351):   at QCARUnity.CheckInitializationError () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.825: I/Unity(18351):   at QCARBehaviour.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.825: I/Unity(18351):  
07-02 14:59:26.825: I/Unity(18351): (Filename:  Line: -1)
07-02 14:59:26.855: D/dalvikvm(18351): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.androchill.socialsquare.fingerprintdemo/lib/libQCARWrapper.so 0x41efb450
07-02 14:59:26.855: E/Unity(18351): Unable to find QCARWrapper
07-02 14:59:26.860: D/dalvikvm(18351): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.androchill.socialsquare.fingerprintdemo/lib/libQCARWrapper.so 0x41efb450
07-02 14:59:26.860: E/Unity(18351): Unable to find QCARWrapper
07-02 14:59:26.860: I/Unity(18351): DllNotFoundException: QCARWrapper
07-02 14:59:26.860: I/Unity(18351):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) QCARNativeWrapper:rendererRenderVideoBackground (int)
07-02 14:59:26.860: I/Unity(18351):   at QCARNativeWrapper.RendererRenderVideoBackground (Int32 bindVideoBackground) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.860: I/Unity(18351):   at QCARManagerImpl.RenderVideoBackgroundOrDrawIntoTextureInNative () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.860: I/Unity(18351):   at QCARManagerImpl.PrepareRendering () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.860: I/Unity(18351):   at QCARBehaviour.OnPreCull () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.860: I/Unity(18351):  
07-02 14:59:26.860: I/Unity(18351): (Filename:  Line: -1)
07-02 14:59:26.900: D/dalvikvm(18351): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.androchill.socialsquare.fingerprintdemo/lib/libQCARWrapper.so 0x41efb450
07-02 14:59:26.900: E/Unity(18351): Unable to find QCARWrapper
07-02 14:59:26.905: D/dalvikvm(18351): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.androchill.socialsquare.fingerprintdemo/lib/libQCARWrapper.so 0x41efb450
07-02 14:59:26.905: E/Unity(18351): Unable to find QCARWrapper
07-02 14:59:26.905: I/Unity(18351): DllNotFoundException: QCARWrapper
07-02 14:59:26.905: I/Unity(18351):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) QCARNativeWrapper:rendererEnd ()
07-02 14:59:26.905: I/Unity(18351):   at QCARNativeWrapper.RendererEnd () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.905: I/Unity(18351):   at QCARManagerImpl.FinishRendering () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-02 14:59:26.905: I/Unity(18351):   at QCARBehaviour.OnPostRender () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I then tried instantiating QCARUnityPlayer instead of UnityPlayer, but then I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError:

```
07-02 15:04:26.830: I/QCAR(26661): onSurfaceCreated
07-02 15:04:26.830: W/dalvikvm(26661): No implementation found for native Lcom/qualcomm/QCAR/QCAR;.onSurfaceCreated:()V
07-02 15:04:26.860: W/dalvikvm(26661): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412522a0)
07-02 15:04:26.860: E/AndroidRuntime(26661): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1638
07-02 15:04:26.860: E/AndroidRuntime(26661): java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [GLThread 1638]
07-02 15:04:26.860: E/AndroidRuntime(26661): Unity version     : 4.1.5f1
07-02 15:04:26.860: E/AndroidRuntime(26661): Device model      : samsung GT-N7100
07-02 15:04:26.860: E/AndroidRuntime(26661): Device fingerprint: samsung/t03gxx/t03g:4.1.2/JZO54K/N7100XXDMC3:user/release-keys
07-02 15:04:26.860: E/AndroidRuntime(26661): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.qualcomm.QCAR.QCAR.onSurfaceCreated:()V
07-02 15:04:26.860: E/AndroidRuntime(26661):    at com.qualcomm.QCAR.QCAR.onSurfaceCreated(Native Method)
07-02 15:04:26.860: E/AndroidRuntime(26661):    at com.qualcomm.QCARUnityPlayer.QCARUnityPlayer.onSurfaceCreated(QCARUnityPlayer.java:39)
07-02 15:04:26.860: E/AndroidRuntime(26661):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1494)
07-02 15:04:26.860: E/AndroidRuntime(26661):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

I've followed [this tutorial](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/unity-how-can-i-extend-unitys-android-activity) as well as pretty much everything else I can find and still can't figure it out.

My fragment code:

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

public class MyFragment extends SherlockFragment {

private UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;

// UnityPlayer.init() should be called before attaching the view to a layout. 
// UnityPlayer.quit() should be the last thing called; it will terminate the process and not return.

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(getActivity()); // Put your activity object here
    int glesMode = mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
    boolean trueColor8888 = false;
    mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

    // Get the view - e.g. to return from the fragment method onCreateView:
    View view = mUnityPlayer.getView();
    return view;
}

public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    mUnityPlayer.quit();
}

// onPause()/onResume() must be sent to UnityPlayer to enable pause and resource recreation on resume.
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mUnityPlayer.pause();
    if (getActivity().isFinishing())
        mUnityPlayer.quit();
}
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mUnityPlayer.resume();
}
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mUnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
}

// Pass any keys not handled by (unfocused) views straight to UnityPlayer
public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int count, KeyEvent event)
{
    return mUnityPlayer.onKeyMultiple(keyCode, count, event);
}
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    return mUnityPlayer.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    return mUnityPlayer.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

My question is, *how can I force Unity/Vuforia to work in a SherlockFragment?*

Comment: Are you trying to have both Vuforia and Unity running at the same time?

Comment: I'm using the Vuforia extension for Unity. My intent is to export my Unity project and integrate it into a regular Android app using a SherlockFragment

Comment: it seems that the Vuforia library QCARWrapper is not found. Make sure it is included in your project. also open the build path to make sure it's included and selected. Also make sure that the order of the libraries is higher that the src folder.

Comment: Same question here. Did you finally solve it, @EricAhn ?

Comment: @RJJ I did eventually end up solving it, but unfortunately I don't remember how as it was almost two years ago.